# SpringIntegration and Reactive: Trying to understand the constraints

Tags: servlets, spring-integration, spring-webflux, reactive, declarative

We have a SpringIntegration workflow with restful HTTP inbound calls and outbound calls.  The workflow is mostly expressed with XML declarations of channels, chains, a splitter and an aggregator.

In the `Servlet` realm, we use the `http:inbound-gateway` and `http:outbound-gateway` components for input/output to the internal workflow.  This seems to work well using SpringBoot `autoconfiguration` for Tomcat/Jetty/Undertow.

We've been trying the `Reactive` realm, using `webflux:inbound-gateway` and `webflux:outbound-gateway` components on the same internal workflow.  This seems to work OK for `tomcat` and `jetty` servers but getting no responses from `netty` and some errors from `undertow`.  I have yet to discover why we are getting errors from the last two configurations.

What I'm wondering is if the same internal workflow can be hooked up to `reactive` or `servlet` components without requiring changes.  We do use a splitter/aggregator, and my reading of the SpringIntegration documentation sections on WebFlux hasn't quite cleared up for me if these constructs can be used in both realms.  ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#splitter-and-aggregator )

Any pointers on this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `webflux:inbound-gateway` is a server side of HTTP protocol. Has to be used in the Reactive Streams HTTP server environment. Not sure about Undertow and Jetty, but Tomcat works in the simulating mode. I usually use an `io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http`.

The `webflux:outbound-gateway` is a client side of HTTP protocol. It is fully based on the `WebClient` and doesn't matter in what environment it is used.

same applies for a splitter and aggregator components: they don't require any server implementation and they don't expose any external ports to worry about some specifics. Can simply be used in the reactive stream definition and in regular flows.